# How do I adjust the position of an imageview in a uicollectionview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIImageView in a UICollectionView cell whose size I am adjusting programmatically based on screen size. The cells create two columns and I want the images to appear closer to the center of the screen when viewing the collection.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel?.text = fetchName()
    cell.myImage?.image = fetchImage()

    if(indexPath.item % 2 == 0) {
        cell.myImage?.frame.origin.x = (cell.frame.size.width / 3) * 2
        cell.myImage?.frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height / 2
    }
    else {
        cell.myImage?.frame.origin.x = (cell.frame.size.width / 3)
        cell.myImage?.frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height / 2
    }

    cell.myImage?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.myImage?.frame.size.width)! / 2
    cell.myImage?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

This doesn't seem to actually move the image view at all though. I also tried adjusting cell.myImage?.center but this didn't have any effect either. So how do I move my image around this cell?

Comment: can you share screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adjusting the position for you `imageView` in your `ProfileCollectionViewCell` `layoutSubviews` method this is the place to do what you want to achieve

I hope this helps you